# При скроллинге (колёсик) мышью меняется что-то, как сделать так, чтобы это что-то не происходило на определенном div?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть код на js при скроллинге мышью меняется что, как сделать так, чтобы это что-то не происходило на определенном div?

```
// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Дать определенному диву ид и прописать что он должен делать

Comment: @ MegaRoks Уважаемый, я делал предыдущую тему с конкретикой, вот ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951409/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-article

Comment: @MegaRoks прошу вас помочь мне. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Как я понял, надо чтобы на третьем блоке не работал горизонтальный скрол?

Comment: @MegaRoks нет. надо чтобы горизонатальный скрол с контентом работал если курсор находится в <article class="mario">, когда курсор в нём, чтобы не работал вертикальный скрол смены блоков. Как только курсор находиться в не <article class="mario">, то начинает работать скрол вертикальный смены блоко и не работать скрол горизонтальный в <article class="mario">. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил. Вы меня понимаете?

Comment: Нет, распиши ` надо чтобы горизонатальный скрол с контентом работал если курсор находится в <article class="mario">, когда курсор в нём, чтобы не работал вертикальный скрол смены блоков`. Если курсо в классе `mario` то работал только вертикальный скрол клаcснf `mario`, а не горизонтальный скрол контента, а если не в классе `mario` то толбко вертикальный? Правильно?

Comment: @MegaRoks Наоборот. Если курсор в классе mario, то работает только горизонтальный скрол, тот который позволяет листать контент по горизонтали. Если не в классе mario, то работает только вертикальный скрол, который меняе блоки.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave Делаешь если мышь пришла с контента на класс `mario` то включаешь overflow-x, а overflow-y выключаешь, и наоборот если пришла на класс контант с класса `mario` то включаешь overflow-y, а overflow-x выключаешь. Но я бы сделал это каруселью, намного проще

Comment: @MegaRoks похоже вы не знаете. смысл отключать overflow, когда любой контент распределяется по горизонтали автоматически? Любая карусель ограничена то что в ней. возможно я вас не понял. если так, то прошу показать пример в сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос на [английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962729/how-to-make-the-mouse-scroll-not-act-on-a-specific-article) был переведен не совсем точно, отвечу здесь и в предыдущую тему.
Для [тестового сайта](http://test.ooo-pnu.ru/) делаем такие вставки кода:

**index.js:**

```
var isHorizontal = false; //Global variable

function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
```

**horisontalscroll.js:**

```
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorizontal = true;    

  // skipped

  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorizontal = false;
  }
```

Comment: Добрый вечер Сергей. Можете помочь с кодом? Я хочу сделать так, чтобы на определенных div (с ид или по классам, как угодно), например дивы со скроллинговым текстом, чтобы их можно было крутить и в это время не работала прокрутка страниц колёсиком.

Comment: Используйте в обработчиках event.stopPropagation()

Comment: Да, уже решил. Если вам будет интересно, то загляните вот в эти вопросы, пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960283 Здорово совместит бы оба варианта.

Comment: Вот со свайпом я совсем не сталкивался еще. Все больше по десктопам...

Comment: код свайпа в теме уже есть. нужно для направления сделать как колесиком. Спасибо.