# Как сделать кнопки для прокрутки контента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой блок с горизонтальной прокруткой контента. Если использовать колесик мышки, то контент разделенный на колонки, плавно переходит от одной колонки к другой, ровно перелистывается информация колесиком. Как сделать аналог с кнопками влево/вправо, чтобы тоже можно было также плавно переходит с одной колонки на другую, как если бы использовать колесик мыши?

PS. У меня есть ещё такой вопрос: [Горизонтальная прокрутка работает колесиком мышки. Как сделать аналог свайпом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/)
Эти вопросы разные, кодом тоже отличаются чуть. В том - аналог прокрутки как колесиком мыши через Swipe, тут - кнопками (см. кнопки желтые по-бокам). В идеале бы сделать Свайп + кнопки в одном.

```js
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorizontal = true;
  var that = this;
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);
  
  var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
      actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;
  
  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorizontal = false;
  }
  
}

function getColumnWidth(that){
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
  var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
  var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
  return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
      distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
      defaultScrollShift = 30,
      savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
      scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;
  
  if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
  }else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
  }
  
  if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
    that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
    return true;
  }
  
  if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
  return false;
}

                        
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
    for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
      elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#prev {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
#next {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
}

.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}



.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
.customtext {
text-align: justify;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 40px;
text-align: justify;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="poscustomtext"><article class="mario"><div id="prev"></div><div id="next"></div><div class="customtext">
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/abca98b122166092.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/abca98b1/22166092_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В ту пору, когда&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;была анонсирована, мода на стелс-экшены только-только начинала зарождаться, и любой мало-мальски приличный проект, хоть как-то позволяющий игроку бесшумно расправляться с неприятелями, сразу же нарекали “слелсом” и сталкивали лоб в лоб с&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Solid</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Это только потом выяснится, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;вообще-то есть много и от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, и даже от&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Driver</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Да и сама по себе боевая система, включая знаменитую (да-да, ту самую, что позже будет популяризована не без помощи&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil 4</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) камеру из-за плеча, куда ближе к&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, нежели детищу&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Konami</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Но маркетинг ведь - штука сродни эпидемии: что надуют в ушко - в то и уверуешь.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И все было бы ничего, кабы датой релиза не значился конец 2001-го, а в качестве целевой платформы не был бы выбран Dreamcast. Тут даже к Ванге не ходи, чтобы понять всю абсурдность подобного решения - от консоли в ту пору уже публично открестилась даже сама&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Sega</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, а мир с замиранием сердца ждал релиза второй части похождений Снейка. Неудивительно, что в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;в итоге сыграли три с половиной человека, а про вышедший спустя полгода PS2-порт львиная доля владельцев данной консоли даже и не слыхивала.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">А жаль, ведь игра вполне себе могла претендовать на лавры одного из лучших консольных экшенов того поколения. Что еще интереснее - перед нами практически уникальный пример проекта, на 80% состоящего из откровенной копипасты, но при этом умело связанной в единое и уж очень гармоничное целое. Причем, как это ни странно, даже обладающего своим узнаваемым лицом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/ef190be422166093.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/ef190be4/22166093_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И хотя разработкой занималась никому доселе не известная шведская студия&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, высоко задранную планку качества ощущаешь уже с первых минут. Оркестровые мотивы за авторством&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Ричарда Жака</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;(британского композитора, к тому времени уже сделавшего себе громкое имя благодаря внушительному списку “сеговских” проектов) пробирают до глубины души. FMV-вставки с “живыми” актерами, стилизованные под новостную сводку, удивляют не на шутку. Равно как и агитационные плакаты, которые можно наблюдать на экране загрузок.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Но вот уж где геймера ждет настоящий шок, так это на поприще графики. Великолепные модели персонажей (удивило разве что отсутствие мимики, да и сами лица объективно слабее, чем в той же&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Code Veronica</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">) и потрясающая детализация окружения, которую ранее, в основном, можно было наблюдать лишь на рендренных фонах - вот чего точно не следовало ожидать от безвестной команды шведов. Движок при этом очень редко дает сбои в виде просадки fps, а сама по себе картинка смотрится очень гладкой и четкой.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Слегка придя в себя от поросячьего восторга, начинаешь разбираться в деталях сюжета. В принципе, ничего из ряда вон здесь игра уже предложить не может. Завязка достаточно стандартна - по крайней мере, если проводить аналогии с художественными фильмами. Главный герой в лице Джека Вейда просыпается в госпитале, где встречается с дочерью убитого основателя ACN - крупнейшей корпорации, служащей законодательным органом будущего. Принципы ее функционирования очень просты - группа специальных агентов, именуемых “хэдхантерами”, выслеживает опаснейших преступников, после чего берет под стражу и отправляет в подводную тюрьму. Там провинившимся супостатам предлагается принять участие в гладиаторской битве на арене. В случае проигрыша ACN имеет право распорядиться внутренними органами потерпевшего фиаско человека на свое усмотрение.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Когда-то Джек и сам был “охотником за головами”, причем номером один. Именно поэтому Энджи и просит нашего героя помочь ей в расследовании убийства. Вот только те самые загадочные события, что привели Джека к больничной койке и амнезии, послужили причиной аннулирования “хэдхантерской” лицензии. Так что, процесс сбора мозаики под названием “Убийство Кристофера Штерна” придется объединить с так называемым “возвращением в школу”.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Поначалу сюжет развивается довольно-таки плавно. В лучших традициях&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;основную массу ключевых фактов можно подцепить не из роликов (здесь они представлены как в виде кат-сцен на движке, так и CG-видео), а при помощи различных документов и записок, так что не ленитесь осматривать каждый уголок. Однако ближе к финалу вектор развития кардинально сменится, шагнув от былого (уж простите за небольшой спойлер) футуристического детектива в сторону научной фантастики с характерными для нее нотками антиутопии.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/322911f922166094.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362396/322911f9/22166094_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">С точки же зрения геймплея,</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">&nbsp;Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;представляет собой достаточно интересный симбиоз сразу нескольких проектов, названия которых были обозначены в самом начале статьи. Передвижение между ключевыми точками осуществляется верхом на байке, модель управления которым достаточно своеобразна. Да и сам город отличается на редкость убогой проработкой - страшненькие здания с размазанными текстурками, полнейшее отсутствие интерактивности и жителей на улицах. Что таким образом пытались нам показать разработчики - решительно непонятно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Основное же действие будет разворачиваться на локациях закрытого типа, как правило отличающихся внушительными размерами. Набор самый стандартный: заправка, офисное здание, морской порт, торговый центр. В ряде случаев будет необходимо решить какую-нибудь головоломку, как правило построенную на стандартном скелете “возьми предмет там и примени его здесь”. В общем, ничего особенного - поклонники&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Silent Hill</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;и&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Resident Evil</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;справятся в два счета.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Куда интереснее дела обстоят с экшен-составляющей, изрядно смахивающей на серию&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Syphon Filter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. Герой достаточно подвижен - например, может лихо троллить своих врагов, перекатываясь из стороны в сторону. Да, сейчас это уже никого не удивляет, но тогда смотрелось вполне себе в новинку. Вы, конечно же, не поверите, но одной из первых игр (самой первой, если что, был дремучий экшен&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">WinBack</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;1999 года розлива) с пресловутой возможностью стрелять из-за угла или баррикад стала именно&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunder</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Арсенал у Джека самый стандартный - пистолет, дробовик, автомат, гранатомет и еще парочка взрывоопасных экземпляров. Единственное новаторство - это пустые гильзы, которые можно использовать для привлечения врагов. Правда, рассчитать траекторию полета оных с высокой точностью порой оказывается достаточно трудно, так что назвать все эту затею хорошей и удобной язык не повернется. Лучше уж старое-доброе “снейковское” простукивание стен.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">К слову, о&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Metal Gear Soild</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">. В игре есть ровным счетом три незначительных момента, которые, собственно, и роднят детище&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; text-decoration-line: underline;">Кодзимы</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;с нашим пациентом. Первое - стелс-миссии, с которыми придется регулярно иметь дело в процессе получения лицензий. Тут уж действительно настоящий "стелс" - никакого оружия кроме собственных рук, с помощью которых Джек не прочь свернуть вражескую шею и вышеупомянутые гильзы. Второе - это оформление самой виртуальной реальности, внутри которой и будет проходить выполнение тестов. Наконец, последнее - это часы с возможностью совершения видеозвонка. Эдакий продвинутый вариант знаменитого кодека.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И, наконец, отдельным пунктом хотелось выделить боссов, в работе над которыми&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Amuze</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">постаралась как следует. Особой харизмой здешние злодеи похвастаться не могут, однако куда важнее для нас тот факт, что каждая битва строго уникальна и требует сугубо индивидуального подхода к тому или иному супостату. Никакой рутиной в духе “хоровод вокруг громилы с последующим “спусканием” в его тушку всего имеющегося арсенала” здесь не пахнет и подавно.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"></p>
<div style="box-sizing: inherit; color: #555555; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400;"><a href="http://vfl.ru/fotos/fa38ef5422166095.html" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" style="box-sizing: inherit; background-color: transparent; color: #2fb5d2; text-decoration-line: none; touch-action: manipulation;"><img src="http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1529362397/fa38ef54/22166095_m.jpg" border="0" alt="user posted image" style="box-sizing: inherit; border-style: none; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"></a></div>
<p style="box-sizing: inherit; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; font-size: 0.9375rem; color: #7a7a7a; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, Ariel;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Подводя итоги, хочется сказать, что судьба&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">&nbsp;все же очень печальна. Конечно, даже с натяжкой игра не способна называться хитом, поскольку мелких огрехов хватает и в геймплее, и сюжете. Да и сама по себе концепция, отличающаяся засильем клише, все-таки не может претендовать на значимые лавры. В то же время, перед нами очень качественный проект, который вполне мог бы принести своим создателям больше денег, а для владельцев PS2 и DC стать куда более значимым (в плане известности) подарком, нежели он является. Хотя, впрочем, лучше уж быть эдаким lost treasure, чем служить пустым местом.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">***</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">И напоследок… о сиквеле замолвите слово.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">В 2004-м году на PS2 и Xbox вышло продолжение под названием&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">, действие которого разворачивалось спустя 20 лет с момента окончания оригинальной игры. За прошедшие годы виртуальный мир сильно изменился - теперь это уже был чистейший киберпанк с присущими для него неоновыми небоскребами, а нотки антиутопии заиграли еще сильнее. Как итог - жителей города распределили между двумя кастами, низшей и высшей.</span><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><br style="box-sizing: inherit;"><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">Несмотря на ряд объективных достоинств, плохого в&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit; font-weight: bolder;">Headhunter: Redemption&nbsp;</span><span style="box-sizing: inherit;">было куда больше. Это и невнятный сюжет, и странное управление с какой-то совершенно недекватной системой прицеливания. Наконец, сменив сеттинг, игра сильно сдала в плане разнообразия локаций. Да и сам по себе графический движок по меркам 2004 года смотрелся просто достойно, но не более того.</span></p>
</div></article></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div></div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Горизонтальная прокрутка работает колесиком мышки. Как сделать аналог свайпом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/%d0%93%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc) - не надо создавать дубль.

Comment: @And вопросы разные.

Comment: @And Похоже нет таких, кто может.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev похоже с Вашей версткой Вам же и разбираться, это не фриланс биржа тут человек отвечает, если ему хочется =), а Вы не задаете вопрос, Вы просите сделать работу за Вас

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я не спорю. кому хочется, я отдаю почти всю свою репутацию.

Comment: вопрос от этого не стал привлекательнее, как и 2 других про это же

Comment: @Stranger in the Q что за бред. Я не прошу построить весь сайт. То что я буду использовать, буду использовать в личных целях. Во всяком случае тут или нет - я добьюсь этого. И, когда я помогаю тут, то просто помогаю. Хотите или нет, знаете или нет - ваше право. Это я понял.

Comment: Вы приводите простыню кода, весьма посредственного качества и предлагаете нам с ним разобраться, это прямое неуважение а нам, к нашему личному времени, почитайте как задать хороший вопрос и перестанете минусы ловить =) отладка логики со свайпом подразумевает наличие у отвечающего возможность проверить всю эту кросс-браузерность-девайсность

Comment: что бы решить ваш вопрос, ваш код нужно рефакторить, иначе любое решение будет костылем, но дам подсказку, у вас уже есть функция `scrollElementToColumn`, используйте ее

Comment: Ты в курсе, что скроллить можно не только колёсиком мыши, но и за скроллбар?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q В данной теме есть вопрос и он звучит так: «Как сделать кнопки для прокрутки контента?» Более того, есть код, уже с кнопками, достаточно его посмотреть на весь экран. К ид кнопок привязать условия, так, чтобы это работало.

Comment: @ThisMan 26 Логически и я знаю. Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy В курсе. И?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023

Comment: @Stranger in the Q И уберите, пожалуйста, все свои наставленные минуса.

Comment: @Qwertiy  и если ставили минуса, то, пожалуйста - уберите. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023

Comment: @VladimirRodichev, я не ставил. Ни там, ни тут.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда, будьте добры, помогите убрать минусы. В будущем постараюсь быть и вам полезен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не совсем уловил зачем изобретать велосипед, когда его уже изобрели.
Хотя может я как не JS программист, не понимаю до конца какой то тонкости.

Вообщем есть такой замечательный плагин: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin
Много из того, что ты озвучил, в нем уже нашло решение.

Резюмируя нашу переписку в комментариях - вот вам решение:

```
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorizontal = true;
  var that = this;
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
      actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;

  console.log(e);

  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorizontal = false;
  }

}

function horizontalClick(that, to){
  isHorizontal = true;

  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = actualColumn + to;

  if(!scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    isHorizontal = false;
  }
}

function getColumnWidth(that){
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
  var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
  var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
  return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
      distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
      defaultScrollShift = 30,
      savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
      scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;

  if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
  }else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
  }

  if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
    that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
    return true;
  }

  if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
  return false;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  var nb;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }

  $("#next").on('click', function() {
    horizontalClick(elems[0], 1);
  });

  $("#prev").on('click', function() {
    horizontalClick(elems[0], -1);
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
    for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
      elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

Можете произвольно управлять "шагом" изменяя параметры в вызове horizontalClick

P.S. Оптимизируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш код.
P.S.S. Я не Ява программист. Извините, если что не так.

Comment: Я бы ответил комментарием, но репутации не хватает.

Comment: Повысим репутацию :) да и предложение правильное, как раз для ТС копи-пастера

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Если бы вы прочли внимательно, то бы увидели что свайп у меня уже вписанный есть, но в другой, аналогичной теме, здесь вопрос только по кнопкам. Решение приведенное вами не годиться. Тут и конструкция другая.

Comment: Я не говорил, что это решение в нужном Вам виде. Нет, вам стоит отказаться от того, что вы напридумывали и обратить внимание на реализацию автора плагина.

Почему я вам именно это посоветовал: во-первых нет слушателей событий. Что уже облегчает работу скрипта. Во-вторых более гибкое обращение с функционалом пространства. В-третьих: нет перебора элементов. Представьте как each будет огромные статьи перелапачивать и вешать слушатель на каждый элемент?

Comment: for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }

----------

Вы же понимаете, что это кощунство а не решение. Перебирать циклами код и вешать на все слушатель?

Comment: Используя решения плагина, Вы закроете свои задачи в большинстве. Если загляните в документацию, то он поддерживает все нужные вам события кроме mousewheel, но мне кажется 5 строчек кода слушателя mousewheel и вызов нужной вам функции плагина (в зависимости от направление mousewheel), закроют и эту потребность.

Comment: @alex Roosso Мне нужно решение управление данным способом - листать контент симметрично по горизонтали. То что вы предложили - свайп, у меня он уже есть. Но это ведь способ управления не данным контентом по горизонтали, столбцы для которого расчитываются автоматически в зависимости от содержимого. Кратко, я не совсем понимаю как написать условие например для: $('ИДкнопки вправо').on('click', function () { условие .... (для прокрутки)

Comment: Попробую иначе пояснить свою мысль... Как работает текущая версия mousewheel? При загрузке страницу, цикл перебирает нужные вам элементы, вешая на каждый слушатель, который ожидает действий от колеса мышки... Сама по себе такая архитектура не кажется Вам избыточной? Ладно... давайте отвлечемся от Вашего любимого велосипеда. Вы пробовали найти другую реализацию для Ваших нужд? Я за много лет в программировании отлично знаю, что к любому решению есть десяток путей. У самого такое бывало не раз, что упираюсь в какую либо задачу и "зависаю"... Может стоит осмотреться?

Comment: Добавил к своему ответу решение Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Сработало решение?

Comment: @alex Roosso Я от вас не получал никаких уведомлений, ответ увидел чисто случайно, зайдя в свой вопрос. Однозначно решение есть. Я скоро проверю. Спасибо вам.

Comment: @alex Roosso ну вот, вы не программист js, но, смогли! Вы настоящий молодец. Результат я обновлю позже черновой. Следующий мой вопрос продолжит данную тему, касаться он будет страниц. Было бы здорово сделать нумерацию страниц. Очень круто!

Comment: @alex Roosso Я хочу с вами подружиться. Давайте держаться вместе. В моем профиле есть страница на вк. но, также мои данные можете найти на моем скромном сайте usphere.ru Автор creator

Comment: @alex Roosso https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/

Comment: @alex Roosso Работает. Но, если нажать быстро в разные стороны, то подергивания начинаются.

Comment: @alex Roosso я инженер, не программист. В плане инженерии, конструкция более чем устраивает. Для того, чтобы найти программное решение - вы предлагаете мне стать программистом? Про варианты, я знаю, не вы один так работайте. Не смотря на то, что вы сделали решение для кликов, подергивания есть. Я хорош в своём деле - визуализация, конструкции.