# Как предотвратить прокрутку страницы при прокрутке дочернего компонента с свойством overflow-y: scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть страница, есть всплывающий компонент. В компоненте контента много. Задал max-height: 95vh, и overflow-y: scroll. Но иногда, когда ползунок компонента в крайних положениях, начинает прокручиваться вся страница. А я не хочу. Пробовал onScroll={(e)=>e.stopPropagination()} - не помогает. Как быть?

Comment: Приложите код с вашим вариантом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокрутка страницы может выполнятся самыми разнообразными способами. Ниже представлен пример, предотвращающий прокрутку колёсиком мышки (или устройством заменяющим мышь). Если был достигнут верх блока, а колесо вращается вверх, или если был достигнут низ блока, а колесо вращается вниз, то действие по умолчанию отменяется. Аналогичным образом можно запретить прокрутку блоков с помощью клавиатуры или взмахов на сенсорном экране.

```
var block = document.getElementById('cc1');
block.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  if (block.scrollTop == 0 && event.deltaY < 0 || block.scrollTop + block.clientHeight == block.scrollHeight && event.deltaY > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: 1. почему не слушать "scroll" евент, вместо колесика, клавиатуры и свайпов по отдельности? 2. это же реакт, какие `getElementById`?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, из моего понимания задачи нужно избежать только определённого вида прокрутки, а не совсем её заблокировать. Учтите, что событие 'scroll' связано только с прокручиваемым элементом. Поэтому когда начинается прокрутка содержимого страницы, уже нельзя понять, чем она вызвана, в каком месте находится курсор, и нужно ли её отменять.

Comment: По поводу реакта. Я считаю, что лучше предоставить максимально универсальный вариант. Но вы можете преложить решение специализированное для React.