# Как сделать условие на js - если курсор мыши на div с id="xx" - происходит какое-то действие?

Tags: javascript

Прошу написать вас условие если курсор мыши находиться на блоке (`<div id="12">` к примеру), то появляется текст «Привет!» или на ваш выбор.
Спасибо.

[Как сделать чтобы прокрутка мыши не действовала на определенном article?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951409/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-article/951631#951631)

В третьем блоке есть горизонтальная прокрутка с контентом, хочется, чтобы при наведении мыши на блок с контентом, при использования колесика мыши одновременно не работало смена экранов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  alert("Hello, world!");
});
```

```css
#foo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Ещё пример:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("div")].forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    if(item.id === "foo") { 
      console.log("foo");
    }
    
    // if(e.target.getAttribute("id") === "foo") {
    //   console.log("foo");
    // }
  });
})
```

```css
#foo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#baz {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}

#faz {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="baz"></div>
<div id="faz"></div>
```

Comment: Можете мне помочь, пожалуйста.. Я обновил дополнение вопроса в эту ветку и оставил ссылку. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  alert("Hello, world!");
}); Как создать условие if "Hello, world" else "Too good"?

Comment: @VladimirRodichev, не понял вопроса, перефразируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: уже решили другим способом. Спасибо большое.